# can we get location details(latitude,longitude)when iphone is in air plane mode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gps, cllocationmanager, airplane-mode

I want to get latitude and longitude values using my app,when iphone is in Air Plane mode.Does GPS work in air plane mode?

Comment: Have you tried it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1355

GPS is turned off in airplane mode, according to Apple.

Comment: yes, but some air carriers have in-flight WiFi so the phone doesn't have to be in full blown airplane mode in the air

Comment: then he can see in the tv screen, even speed and outside temperature ;)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get location data via WiFi without GPS.

Comment: I have tried this.I put my phone in to Airplane mode and tried to get location details.Sometimes it takes latitude and longitude values,sometimes it is not and it throws a kCLErrorLocationUnknown error.But according to Apple when Airplane mode, it should not take any signals.but sometimes it takes.If anyone know the reason for this please post.Thank you :)